# How to share a printer between two computers on different networks without password?

Tags: printer, network-shares

I'm trying to share a USB printer connected to PC1 over wifi to PC2. Everything connects fine and i can see the printer share from PC2. The only problem is PC2 keep asking for a password even thought i disabled password-protected sharing on PC1. The same problem doens't happen on another pc on the same network as PC1.

Is there any issue with sharing printers over different networks or any issue with a previous saved password to access shares on PC1?

Both PCs have Windows Vista x86, PC1 has IP 192.168.80.x and PC2 is on 192.168.0.x on wifi. The wifi router has an IP 192.168.80.y.

Comment: It seems both computers are connected to the same network.  This must be true because its not possible to share a printer with another computer not connected to the same network.

Comment: Have you tried the remember password checkbox, while entering username and password

Comment: @Ramhound It's just that the wifi is a router so the PC2 can see PC1, but PC1 can't see PC2 which is behind the router.

Comment: @Deloader Yes, I've tried that without success. I can save the password, but as soon as the user logs out and log back in, the password doesn't work. It seems Windows Vista and Seven no longer saves the passwords after the user logout. At least without AD.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if you create a user on PC1 with the same login and password as the user on PC2 trying to print, there will be no more password checking.
I think this is the easiest solution but there are other ways to do it if this one is not adequate.

Comment: I'll try that. Any specifics on permissions for the user (Administrator, User, Guest)?

Comment: Admin or user will work. Guest, not sure but I think there may be a way to share the printer for guests too.